# Using boost::upgrade_lock and shared_lock to implement read/write thread safety

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, thread-safety

```
double x = 10;
boost::shared_mutex xSharedMutex;


void r() {
    boost::shared_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(xSharedMutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        cout << "**** READ **** " << x << endl;
        usleep(200);
    }
}

void w() {
    boost::upgrade_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(xSharedMutex);
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        x = i + 12;
        cout << "---- WRITE ---- " << x <<endl;
        usleep(200);
    }

}

int main() {
    boost::thread t1(&r);
    boost::thread t2(&w);

    sleep(3);
}
```

I expect that read and write will go sequentially because of an upgrade_lock has been added in w(). However, the read and write run simutaneously.

Is the usage of shared_lock and upgrade_lock wrong? How to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You need either unique ownership for writing:

```
boost::unique_lock<boost::shared_mutex> lock(xSharedMutex);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    x = i + 12;
    std::cout << "---- WRITE ---- " << x << std::endl;
    usleep(200);
}
```

Or you can upgrade that lock ad-hoc:

```
upgrade_lock<shared_mutex> lock(xSharedMutex);
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    {
        upgrade_to_unique_lock<shared_mutex> write_lock(lock);
        x = i + 12;
        std::cout << "---- WRITE ---- " << x << std::endl;
    }
    usleep(200);
}
```

Of course, the output in this program gets intermixed as the console output is not under any kind of lock (this is strictly UB)